# Search a string only if another string is present in that file using perl

Tags: perl, file, search

### Background:

I have a Java class called Component which has a method in it named getProperty.
In my source control, there are many other Java classes which instantiate this Component class and invoke getProperty method on that object. 
I want to make modifications to this getProperty method and so want to analyze who all are getting impacted.

### Requirement:

I want to search in all *.java files (spread across multiple directories as per the package name).
The problem is that the getProperty method is not just available only on Component class rather many other class, e.g. System.getProperty or Event.getProperty.
Hence my search results using grep is returning a mixed result. Now i have to scan through each search result to find which of them are relevamt to me (i.e. they are the callers of Component.getProperty method).

One thing is for sure if somebody is going to invoke Component.getProperty method, they would have ensured that they import the Component class explicitly.
ie. import com.abc.xyz.alpha.Component;

So my search alogorithm goes in the direction that if a file has got a string "import com.abc.xyz.alpha.Component;" then only look for the getProperty string in that file. If the file does not have the import statement, then skip that file and proceed to next file.

I need help writing this search in perl. Can somebody please help here?

Thanks for reading thorugh this long post. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Crudely,

```
fgrep -l 'import com.abc.xyz.alpha.Component;' *.java |
xargs fgrep getProperty
```

Or in Perl,

```
perl -0777ne 'print map { "$ARGV:$_\n" } grep { m/getProperty/ } split ("\n")
    if m/import com\.abc\.xyz\.alpha\.Component;/' *.java
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need this for  windows. I do not find fgrep command on windows.